# NoClassDefFoundError, proGuard and tween-engine library

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, libgdx, proguard

I added a library to the project as a .jar file.

I added entry in proGuard:

```
# TweenEnginesLibrary
-libraryjars ../core/libs/tween-engine-api.jar
-keep class aurelienribon.tweenengine.** { *; }
-dontwarn aurelienribon.tweenengine.**

-keep class (...).flappy_dragon.TweenAccessors
-keep class (...).flappy_dragon.TweenAccessors.SpriteAccessor
```

This is mine SpriteAccessor class:

```
package (...).flappy_dragon.TweenAccessors;
​
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Sprite;
import aurelienribon.tweenengine.TweenAccessor;
​
public class SpriteAccessor implements TweenAccessor<Sprite> {
​
    public static final int ALPHA = 1;
​
    @Override
    public int getValues(Sprite target, int tweenType, float[] returnValues) {
        switch (tweenType) {
        case ALPHA:
            returnValues[0] = target.getColor().a;
            return 1;
        default:
            return 0;
        }
    }
​
    @Override
    public void setValues(Sprite target, int tweenType, float[] newValues) {
        switch (tweenType) {
        case ALPHA:
            target.setColor(1, 1, 1, newValues[0]);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

And i still getting error

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: (...).flappy_dragon.TweenAccessors.SpriteAccessor
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2):

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` is caused by a jar file being present at compile time but missing at runtime. The jars you added to your project depend on other jars that also need to be imported to your project.

You should compare your build path and runtime classpath. In Eclipse you can find the former in `Project -> Properties -> Java build Path` and the latter in `Run -> Run Configurations... -> Classpath`

Comment: I am not using Eclipse. I am using android studio and proGuard. I think that i need to add some lines in my proGuard file.

Comment: The IDE you are using makes no difference. If you export the jar then you have to make sure all dependencies are included. (All jars that contain classes other classes depend upon)

Comment: The primary reason for NoClassDefFoundError is as steven35 says: present at compile time, not at runtime. But there's another way it can happen, and that is a class that SpriteAccessor **depends** on was present at compile time, but not at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Is it the case that, your application is working fine in debug build and not working in release build (coz proguard comes into picture only in release build)?

If Yes, there is some problem in providing settings in Proguard.

If No, there is some problem in adding library. In Eclipse, right click over .jar file and go for option 'Add to Build Path'. In Android Studio, check in build.gradle that below code is present.

`dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar']) 
}`

Answer (score 0):

```
# TweenEnginesLibrary
-libraryjars ../core/libs/tween-engine-api.jar
-keep class aurelienribon.tweenengine.** { *; }
-dontwarn aurelienribon.tweenengine.**

-keep class (...).flappy_dragon { *; }
-keep interface (...).flappy_dragon { *; }
```

Can you try this?

Also you should post full error log. Because it may say to class name that converted. So we can apply proguard better.